# Convert string to date C++

Tags: c++, beginner, datetime, c++17

New to C++ here, by combining different pieces of code I've found, i came with this solution below to convert a date in string to a date object. It works as I want but I'm not certain to do the simplest thing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sstream>
#include <chrono>
#include <ctime>



int main(void)
{
    std::wstring date_time_format = L"%m/%d/%Y";
    std::wistringstream ss{ L"4/28/2022" };
    std::tm dt;

    ss >> std::get_time(&dt, date_time_format.c_str());

    std::time_t final_time;

    final_time = std::mktime(&dt);
    std::tm *ltm = localtime(&final_time);

    std::cout << "Year:" << 1900 + ltm->tm_year<<std::endl;
    std::cout << "Month: "<< 1 + ltm->tm_mon<< std::endl;
    std::cout << "Day: "<< ltm->tm_mday << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Unnecessary use of wide strings

In your example, there is no need to use wide strings for `date_time_format` and `ss`. Just use `std::string` and `std::istringstream` and drop the `L` prefix for the string literals.

## Missing `std::`

You are using `localtime()` without `std::` in front. If you include the C++ versions of the C header files, then there is no guarantee that the C functions will be available in the global namespace.

## Use `'\n'` instead of `std::endl`

Prefer using [`'\n'` instead of `std::endl`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/213907/stdendl-vs-n); the latter is equivalent to the former, but also forces the output to be flushed, which is usually not necessary and has a negative impact on performance.

## Missing error checking

If you are trying to parse strings you don't have full control over, the parsing might fail. You should check that `ss` is still in a good state after trying to parse the date.

## Consider using C++20

If you are stuck with C++17 or earlier, then the code you wrote is the only standards compliant way to parse time. However, the situation has improved in C++20 with the introduction of [`std::chrono::parse()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/parse) and other [calendar features](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono#Calendar). If you are lucky and your compiler and standard library support it already, you can write:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <chrono>

int main()
{
    std::string date_time_format = "%m/%d/%Y";
    std::istringstream ss{ "4/28/2022" };
    std::chrono::year_month_day date;

    ss >> std::chrono::parse(date_time_format, date);

    if (!ss) {
        /* failed to parse date */
        ...
    }

    std::cout << "Year: "  << date.year()  << '\n';
    std::cout << "Month: " << date.month() << '\n';
    std::cout << "Day: "   << date.day()   << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks for your feedback. For the C++20 code, i tried to changed from 17 to 20 but didnt succeed to make it work on my computer, i need to update clang but i'm stuck there

Comment: The issue is not so much in the compiler, but in the standard libraries lagging a bit behind. However, there are external libraries that implement the missing C++20 functionality, for example for `std::chrono::parse()` you can use [Howard Hinnant's date library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date).